# When mail function does not work from serverside then zend mail library give fatal error. How to handdle it

Tags: php, zend-framework

When mail function does not work from serverside then zend mail library give fatal error. How to handdle it.

This is happening when there is a lot of mails sending out. Things are working fine before but from today when a large number of amount of users came to my site and registered the error is shown.

We are sending three mails when some one resister. 
error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:112 
Stack trace: #0 /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Mail.php(973): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail)) 
#2 /home/content/83/6523183/html/application/controllers/RegistrationController.php(156): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): RegistrationController->indexAction()
#4 /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#5 /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#6 /home/content/83/6523183/html/index.php(67): Zend_Cont in /home/content/83/6523183/html/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php  on line 112
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read manual page about [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) first

And then add try-catch block

```
try {
    //here you trying to send mail
} catch(Exception $e) {
    //this code executed if exception was thrown within try block
    //use this block to recover from error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a fatal error it's an **[Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)** therefore you should be able to try { } and :

```
catch(Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception $e) { 
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixing is simple. Solution is difficult.

You can fix it as others suggest - by try/catch block.

But a real solution is to create batch procedure, that will handle the emails (if you are sure, that the number of emails is the problem). I can think of a cron action, that will be called say each minute and it will fetch some (say 5 to 10) emails and messages from database and send them. It may remove them after sucessful send. Therefore all emails will be send (maybe with some delay). If the exception occurs, it won't affect anything - mails will be send next time the CRON is executed

Comment: You're right to mention that he should fix the problem instead of justing catching it, however, such queue can exponentially grow, in some case it is better to use some routing services.

Comment: Indeed, all these ideas about try/catch evade the core question: What do you do in the catch? The email message was not sendable, so....? @Tomáš's suggestion for a message queue addresses this, though @Boris raises a good point about managing the comparative rates at which the queue is fed and consumed.